# SVN: Create a dump file of a folder

Tags: svn

I'm trying to create a dump file of a folder in my SVN repository. (My goal is to import this dump on another repository, but that's another story).

I've read like 20 pages about this and they all tell me to use [svndumpfilter](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svndumpfilter.html), but I can't seem to make it work.

Here is my command:

```
C:\>svnadmin dump d:/SvnData/TestingSVN/ | svndumpfilter include /TestingSVN/Trunk/Fms/ > d:\FMS.txt
```

The output in the command line is this strange thing:

```
Including prefixes:
   '/TestingSVN/Trunk/Fms'
* Dumped revision 0.
Revision 0 com*m iDtutmepde da sr e0v.isi
n 1.
Revision 1 committed as 1.
* Dumped revision 2.
Revision 2 committed a*s  D2u.mpe
 revision 3.
Revisio*n  D3u mcpoemdm irtetveids iaosn  34..
Revision*  4D ucmopmemdi trteevdi saiso n4 .5.
Revision 5 com*m iDtutmepde da sr e5v.isi
n 6.
Revision 6 commi*t tDeudm paesd  6r.evi
ion 7.
Revisio*n  D7u mcpoemdm irtetveids iaosn  78..
Revision *8  Dcuommpmeidt treedv iassi o8n. 9.
Revision 9*  cDoummmpietdt erde vaiss i9o.n 1
.
Revisi*o nD u1m0p ecdo mrmeivtitseido na s1 11.0
.
Revision 11 *c oDmummiptetde dr eavsi s1i1o.n 1
.
Revision 12 committed*  aDsu m1p2e.d r
vision 13.
Revision 13 committ*e dD uamsp e1d3 .rev
sion 14.
Revision 14 commit*t eDdu mapse d1 4r.evi
ion 15.
Revision 15 committed as 15.
* Dumped revision 16.
Revision 16 committed as 16.
Dropped 83 nodes:
   '/Branches'
   '/Branches/305'
   '/Branches/305/New Text Document.txt'
   '/Fms'
   '/Fms/ADPropertySheet.cpp'

etc. for 83 nodes...
```

Also, the dump file itself is only 3 KB and contains no real data, only things like that (this is not the complete dump, just a sample).

```
SVN-fs-dump-format-version: 2
UUID: 592fc9f0-5994-e841-a4dc-653714c95216
Revision-number: 0
Prop-content-length: 56
Content-length: 56
K 8
svn:date
V 27
2009-06-19T15:05:52.001352Z
PROPS-END
Revision-number: 1
Prop-content-length: 112
Content-length: 112
K     7
svn:log
V 38
This is an empty revision for padding.
K 8
svn:date
V 27
2009-06-19T15:11:29.378511Z
PROPS-END
```

How can this be sorted out?

Comment: I fixed your formatting. Use either four space indents or the `{}` button for code (or code-like) formatting.

Comment: @DarkJeff Touched up the formatting for you. For future, you can use the `{}` button to format code-blocks like I've done for you.

Comment: You could always just copy the repository wholesale, and delete the folders you don't want.

Comment: @Malfist This is not a good solution because by doing so, it would keep the history of ALL the change in the repository even if I delete the folders I don't want. The svndumpfilter filter the history and just keep the one that matters, that's why I want to go that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The noisy output is because you are seeing the stderr from both commands in the pipeline mixed together on your console.  If you split this up into two commands it will make more sense:

```
* Dumped revision 0.
* Dumped revision 1.
* Dumped revision 2.
...

Revision 0 committed as 0.
Revision 1 committed as 1.
Revision 2 committed as 2.
...
```

Hopefully you can see that these are getting combined into your single output above.

Otherwise the syntax of your command looks fine.  But is there actually any data at "/TestingSVN/Trunk/Fms"? I ask because I see "/Fms" in the Dropped nodes, and it makes me wonder if perhaps your folder is at a different path than you think it is.  You might want to try 'svn info' on your working copy just to confirm.  I think an include of "Trunk/Fms" or possibly just "Fms" might be appropriate.

Comment: I don't know what is the "svn info" but when I open the repository Browser in tortoise SVN on the FMS folder, the path is: https://svn.yyyyy.com:8443/svn/TestingSVN/Trunk/Fms. So the path seems to be ok... I will keep trying since it seems that I'm in the good direction.

Comment: I tried with only Fms and it worked. I don't realy understand why svndumpfilter ignore the Trunk but it worked! Thanks a lot